# Adding an optional external supply

Tags: power-supply, 5v, vintage

I'm a electronics hobbyist and I have an old computer, a VIC-20, that I like to build hardware peripherals for.  The computer's logic runs on 5V and there's a user port which can supply up to 100mA at 5V on the computer's main VCC line.

I'm designing a 32 pin GPIO board for it. Since the GPIO chips can sink around 30mA per pin, I'm planning to have an optional external supply jack.

However, I'd like it to be able to support projects with smaller amperage requirements which are only powered from the computer's supply.

I've never done an optional external supply and honestly I'm not sure how to approach it.

How can I connect the internal and external supplies together?

Back-feeding 5V into the computer's VCC while it's turned off seems like a bad idea to me.  How can I avoid that?

Is having 5V on TTL input pins bad if the computer is turned off?

Or are there any other pitfalls I may run into that I'm not aware of?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should NOT connect the internal and external supplies together, except for their ground connections.

You should use a switch or a 3-pin jumper that allows you to select whether the +5V for the external logic comes from the computer or from the external supply.

> Is having 5V on TTL input pins bad if the computer is turned off?

Possibly. You should turn on the external supply last and turn it off first. Or you could plug everything into an outlet strip that allows you to switch it all at once.

A third option would be to use the internal power to control the external power:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fGYbdk.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

`SW1` represents the 3-pin jumper that selects internal (upper position) or external (lower position) power. It's OK to disconnect the external supply when using internal power.

Comment: Finally had a chance to give this a try and it works great.  Thanks.